# How do I control whether ZFS arrays show in the devices pane in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, xfce, zfs, automounting

I am using Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 with XFCE as my DE.

I have mounted a zfs array 'big-tank' to /media/big-tank, however, it does not show up in the devices pane. Additionally, the leftover space from a different pool does appear there, in spite of it not being mounted to /media.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ zfs get all big-tank |grep mountpoint
big-tank  mountpoint            /media/big-tank        local
user@ubuntu:~$ ls /media
big-tank  CloudDrive  user  nvme-tank
user@ubuntu:~$ df /media/big-tank
Filesystem      1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
big-tank       7541358208   128 7541358080   1% /media/big-tank
```

but here is my devices pane:

[image]

And here are my zpools:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ zpool list
NAME        SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
big-tank   7.25T   996K  7.25T         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
nvme-tank   928G   409G   519G         -     2%    44%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
user@ubuntu:~$ zfs list
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
big-tank              852K  7.02T    96K  /media/big-tank
nvme-tank             887G  12.1G    24K  /media/nvme-tank
nvme-tank/ext4-zvol   474G   478G  8.28G  -
nvme-tank/ntfs-zvol   413G  24.1G   401G  -
```

1. Why does big-tank not show in devices in spite of being correctly mounted /media/big-tank?
2. Why does nvme-tank show in devices in spite of not being mounted to /media, and having no mountpoint listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why does big-tank not show in devices in spite of being correctly mounted /media/big-tank?

Because `big-tank` is not a (block) device in the first place. That's a ZFS pool. I'm not using Thunar but I believe `/media/bing-tank` is available under "File System".

> 2. Why does nvme-tank show in devices in spite of not being mounted to /media, and having no mountpoint listed?

`nvme-tank` is not a file system but a pool containing two volumes (zvol) which appears under the device pane.

Under ZFS, a pool can be created from one or more disk devices (or possibly just files). A pool contains datasets. Unlike traditional partitions that are isolated from each other, datasets all share the pool space. Datasets can be volumes, file systems or snapshots. The file systems can be mounted anywhere and the volumes might be used to contain non ZFS entities, likely `ext4` and `ntfs` file systems in your case according to the names they were given.

It is well possible that Thunar is confused by ZFS way of doing and fails to properly display its file systems. See for example this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=855307).

Comment: You are correct, nvme-tank is a zpool. It is not a zvol either. Also, I edited my question to include the requested info.
Is the issue that it is DATASETS not ZPOOLS that are mounted?

Comment: What I don't understand is why I can mount the device to /media/big-tank, and use it as normal, but it simply does not appear in "devices" the way other disks mounted there do.

Comment: You do not mount devices to a directory with ZFS. You import pools, and pools contains file systems which are mounted on given mountpoints specified as file system properties. The /etc/fstab file is not used in that process.

Comment: OK I will rephrase the question: How do I make any mountpoint in /media appear in "devices"?

Comment: Under ZFS., mountpoints are not devices in the first place.

Comment: What is the criteria for Thunar to put something under "devices"? Is there some way I can trick it into treating it like a device in the GUI?

Comment: Thunar assumes there is a one to one relationship between devices and file systems. This can't work with ZFS. As the rejected bug reports shows, Thunar developers do not look to consider it an issue so there is nothing you can do. Does this issue prevent you to access ZFS files from XFCE?

Comment: No, it just irritates me.